# How to connect to mysql with encrypted password?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I have a mysql database in development env.

There is username and encryted password in my local configuration so my code can connect to the database.

Now I want to connect to the database by shell so I can run more commands to do trouble shooting.

Is there any way to do this? I believe this is possible since my code can connect to the db with the encrypted password.

Comment: Do you know the unencrypted password?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to print out the unencrypted password, then copy it and connect